# Problem involving the imaginary number i

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

You are given the equation c = (a + bi)^3 - 107i. You need to find the only values for a and b (if you are unfamilar with i it is the square root of -1). My orignal approach was to remove "i" and then just reached a point where I had an equation which isn't exactly intutive to find one solution to find:
2 = log(a^2 + b^2) ^3 + 107 / log c
derived because c^2 = (a^2 + b^2)^3 + 107  so log c^2 = log(a^2 + b^2)^3 + 107 then 2logc = log(a^2 + b^2)^3 + 107 and finally 2 = log(a^2 + b^2) ^3 + 107 / log c
please can someone helo as I haven't been taught this. The problem is from Mathcup and has a solution but no explanation as the users make the solutions(not the answers) https://www.mathcup.com/solutions?globalId=10455

Comment: We need more information, is c a real number?

Comment: it is a postive number so are the others

Comment: and they are integers

Comment: We are told that they are integers and positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finished editing my answer.

$c = a^3 - 3ab^2 + (3a^2b - b^3 - 107)i.$

Equating coefficients of imaginary parts:

$b(3a^2-b^2) = 107.$

$107\ $ is prime and $a,b>0,\ $ so either

$b = 1\ $ and $3a^2 - b^2 = 107 \implies 3a^2 = 108 \implies a = 6,\ $ or

$3a^2 - b^2 = 1\ $ and $\ b = 107 \implies a^2 = \frac{11450}{3} \implies a \notin \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow\Leftarrow. $

So it must be the first case: $b = 1\ $ and $\ a = 6,\ $ and so $\ c = 198.$

Comment: My question or your answer?

Comment: My answer I made mistakes, so I'm going to edit it in a minute.

Comment: Thank you for the solution

Comment: That's fine. You're a new user. Please use mathjax in your question formatting next time. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference